# Choosing an audio API

Tags: audio, windows-7

I'm struggling to choose between a vast number of audio programming languages and APIs. I'm very (totally) new to audio programming so please bear with me.

**Software**

I need to be able to:

1. Alter volume of different sounds before outputting them to anything (these sounds can have a variety of different origins, for example mp3s and microphone input)
2. phase shift sounds
3. superimpose sounds that I have tweaked (as per items 1 and 2)
4. control the output to each of 8 channels independently of one another
5. make this all happen on Windows7

These capabilities need be abstracted by a graphical frontend I will probably make myself. What I want to be able to do is create 'sound sources' and move them around a 3D environment along either pre-defined trajectories and/or in relation to the movement of whoever is inside the rig. The reason I want to do pitch bending is so I can mess with red-shift stuff.

I don't want to have to construct full tracks before-hand and just play them. I want the sound that is played to depend on external input from sensors as well as what I am doing on the frontend.

As far as I know this means I cant use any existing full audio making app.

**The Question**

I've been looking around for for the API or language I should use and I have not turned up a blank, quite the opposite actually. I'm struggling to narrow down my search. A lot of my problem stems from the fact that I have no experience in audio programming.

So, does anyone know off-hand of an API or language that meets my criteria?

**Hardware stuff and goals**

(I left this until last because I'm not sure how relevant it is)

My goal is to make three rings of speakers at different heights and to have enough control over them to be able to simulate any number of 'sound sources' within the array. The idea is to have someone stand in the middle of the rig and be able to make it sound like there are lots of things moving around them. To get this working I'm planning on doing a little trig and using 8 channels of audio from my PC. The maths is pretty straight forward, it just the rest that I need to worry about

What I want to do next is attach a bunch of cameras to the thing and do some simple image recognition stuff to be able to 'attach sound sources' to different objects. Eg. If someone is standing in the right place it can be made to seem as though all red balls quack like a duck, and all orange ones moan hauntingly.

Comment: Your #2 says "phase shift", but I don't think that's what you mean. You might mean "pitch shift" but the doppler effect (which is what it sounds like you really want) is usually achieved with a variable delay not a pitch shifter.

Answer (score 1):

This is not to detract from Richard Small's answer, but to comment on some of the other options out there:

If you are looking for something higher-level with which you can prototype and develop this faster, you want [max/msp](http://cycling74.com/products/max/) or it's open source competitor [puredata](http://puredata.info/). These are designed for musicians who are technically minded, but not so much for programmers. As a result, you can build this sort of thing quickly and efficiently.

You also have some lower level options: PortAudio can handle your audio I/O, you would have to do the sound generation and effects and so on on your own or with other libraries. Cinder and OpenFramewoks both provide interfaces for audio, cameras, and other stuff for "creative programming". I'm afraid I don't know if they meet your full requirements, but they are powerful and popular for this sort of thing so I encorage you to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

The two major ones these days tend to be

WWise
[WWise Download Link](http://www.audiokinetic.com/en/downloads)

FMOD
[FMOD Download Link](http://www.fmod.org/fmod-downloads.html)

These two engines may even in fact be overkill for what you need, but I can almost guarantee that they will be capable of anything you require.

Comment: Thanks, I've heard about those. I know they are used a lot for game audio and that sort of thing. Pretty cool, but are they suitable for making stuff happen in real time? I've added a couple of points onto my requirements to make stuff a little more clear...